# Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find visible select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I have a simple bootstrap modal with displays a form with dropdown menu and submit button when a user clicks on a link. I try to select options from the dropdown menu with Capybara in an Rspec feature test, but it does not find the dropdown menu.

The feature spec:

```
scenario "User searches records" do
    visit my_records_path

    click_link 'Search Records'

    within('#practiceSearchModal') do
      select('Pennsylvania', from: '#state_search')
      click_on('Submit')
    end
end
```

The modal on the page:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="practiceSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 654px;"></div>
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 750px;">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <select name="state" id="state_search" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
      </select>



    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is error I get with Capybara, it cannot find the select menu with id state_search:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find visible select box "#state_search" that is not disabled within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="div" path="/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div">
 # /home/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7@core/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:314:in `block in synced_resolve'
```

But I see the element on the page:

[image]

Why can't Capybara find the element which I see it on the screen after it clicks the link?

Comment: Sometimes transitions found in modals or hide/unhide functions are a little slower to render. You may need to modify your `select` selector to wait until the `#state_search` is both visible & not disabled. You might be able to add a simple `expect(page).to have_selector('#state_search', visible: true, disabled: false)` assertion that will wait until it appears (inside your within, before your select)

Comment: @JayDorsey that doesn't change anything. And I still see the popup when capybara lunches chrome. So I do see that the dropdown is there. I even added a sleep for 20 seconds, but it still can't find it.

Comment: I'd probably try throwing a `binding.pry` after the `click_link` and inspecting the page both manually (inside chrome) and via the console (by running `find` commands to look at elements, for example). The message you're seeing indicates to me that it's finding the element but one of the two conditions isn't being met. Bootstrap might have disabled the field for some reason. Is one of your describe/scenario blocks tagged with either `:js`, or `js: true`, or do you ahve this tagged as a `feature` spec (or in `feature` folder)?

Comment: @JayDorsey I have Capybara.current_driver = :selenium in background :context before the scenerio is run.

Comment: I also added a screenshot to my question I took when Capybara and Selenium launched chrome to show that the element is there.

Comment: Try from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53662424/capybaraelementnotfound-unable-to-find-visible-select-box/68220155#68220155

Answer (score 2):

The `from` option takes the id, not a CSS selector -

```
select('Pennsylvania', from: ‘state_search')
```

Comment: You can find more information here https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method
*from (String) — The id, Capybara.test_id atrtribute, name or label of the select box*

Comment: I'm certain I've never dug into the documentation for this, and used to using selectors (rather than text) so thank you for answering this. I'm pretty sure I've run into this before and my workaround was to grab the select box using some other handle/method, rather than realizing I had an extraneous `#`

Comment: @JayDorsey You're welcome - technically the :from option is used in a `find` call with the built-in `select` selector (`find(:select, from, ...)` which is why it takes the id/name/etc rather than a CSS selector.  If you did want to use a CSS selector it would need to be something like `find('#state_search').select('Pennsylvania')`

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I think that's how I always ended up going around it before. I just assumed it was an issue w/ DOM behavior not updating/syncing. Do you think a PR that either a) strips the leading `#` if it exists, or b) warns is something that would add value?

Comment: @JayDorsey The issue is that `#state_search` is actually a valid element id - `<select id="#state_search" ... >` so stripping isn't valid and warning would be wrong too.

Comment: @JayDorsey I've managed to come up with something that adds a warning on failure to find - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/pull/2143 - please leave thoughts/feedback on that PR if you have any

Comment: @ThomasWalpole this is awesome. I think a warning is the right balance to provide some context when the docs are missed or misread, or when you use one of the less-often used selectors. Thanks for coming up with a clean solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find("#state_search", visible: false).find("option[value='Pennsylvania']").click
```

Or within scope as:

```
within '#state_search', visible: false do
    find("option[value='Pennsylvania']").click
end
```

Comment: `visible: false` works perfectly with `select picker` plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes some js plugins may add `visible: hidden` onto your select box. You can add the option `visible: :all` to your `select` to help.

Comment: bless you sir... weird how the documentation doesn't seem to mention this